# Bound service and timeout

Tags: android, android-service

In the application that I am developing there is a bound service, that uses TCP socket connection. The requirement for the service is to keep the socket connection for a while after last Activity bound to the service is shut down, say for 1 minute. This is to avoid unneeded socket reconnections when another activity connects to the service just after one has unbound from it.

I have searched and found similar issue ( [Service, Rebind or not bound at all?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4533558/service-rebind-or-not-bound-at-all) ) suggesting using started service, but current application architecture uses bound connections, and I would not like to redesign if it is not needed. Hence I am looking for other options.

My question is, can I somehow postpone bound service destruction or the only good approach is to rewrite the communication to the service using intents, thus converting it to started service?

```
public class SocketService extends Service {

    private static final String LOG_TAG = SocketService.class.getSimpleName();

    @Override
    public final IBinder onBind(final Intent intent) {
        Log.d(LOG_TAG, "onBind()");     
        return new LocalBinder<SocketService>(this);
    }


    @Override
    public boolean onUnbind(Intent intent) {
        Log.d(LOG_TAG, "onUnbind");
        return super.onUnbind(intent);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        Log.d(LOG_TAG, "onCreate");

        // create socket connection here
        // ...
        //

        super.onCreate();
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        Log.d(LOG_TAG, "onDestroy");
        // close socket connection
        // ...
        //
        super.onDestroy();
    }

    // Other socket sending and receiving logic
    // ...
    //
}
```

Thanks in advance for you time.

Answer (score 0):

Keep the First Activity you launch bound to the service , don't destroy it when you launch another one .

When you want to exit the application from your current activity send a signal to the service which will notify all activities to close .

OnCreate is only called on the first bind to the service (when the service doesn't exist ) , the bind that follows should not trigger the onCreate function .

Comment: I think this would not work, at least in my case, AFAIK Android controls when Activities are destroyed. So after user will press "back" on my activity, there is a great chance onDestroy will be called. On the other hand I _must_ unbind in Activity.onDestroy from the service to avoid connection leaks.

Comment: Android doesn't control when activities are destroyed (only in extreme cases) you do by calling finish() . When you launch a new activity if you didn't close the old one your will not trigger a second onCreate in the service and when you decide to destroy your activity or android does (because he needs memory ...) the onDestroy function of the activity will be called and the last one destroyed, it will close the tcp connection and the service to finish .

Comment: I do want the activity to be closed, therefore finished, for example as user pressed "back" key. Still the service should live for a specified amount of time after unbind...